# Reverse method for recursively defined list class

Tags: python, list, recursion, reverse

I have been working on a recursively defined list class in Python and I'm having trouble coding a `reverse()` method to function recursively. Here's the basis for the class.

```
class RecList:
  def __init__(self):
    self._head = None
    self._rest = None
```

The base case would be self._head, being the first entry in a list, followed by the recursive case which is essentially another list containing its own `self._head` to start, then defined recursively. This proceeds all the way down to the bottom level where both `self._head` and `self._rest = None`. Is there a simple way to code a reverse method for a list defined like this?

Comment: Please post an example of usage of your class, including construction of the RecList and "printing" of the created instance.

Comment: Why not simply use collections.deque? It's implemented as a linked list and it's coded in C so it's faster than any pure Python solution ever will be.

Comment: I'm a little hesitant to actually post the source code. Strictly speaking, it isn't mine and this is an assignment for school. I'd really hate to have the entire source up and have the professor find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class RecList:
  def __init__(self, head=None, rest=None):
    self._head = head
    self._rest = rest
  def __str__(self):
    if self._rest is None:
        return str(self._head)
    return str(self._head) + ' ' + self._rest.__str__()
  def reverse(self):
    return self._reverse_aux(None)
  def _reverse_aux(self, acc):
    if self._rest is None:
        return RecList(self._head, acc)
    return self._rest._reverse_aux(RecList(self._head, acc))

lst = RecList(1, RecList(2, RecList(3, None)))
print lst
> 1 2 3
print lst.reverse()
> 3 2 1
```

Comment: Thank you very much this gave me an idea of how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
class RecList:
  def __init__(self, head, tail):
    self.head = head
    self.tail = tail

def foldr(f, acc, xs):
    head = xs.head
    tail = xs.tail

    if tail:
        return foldr(f, f(head, acc), tail)
    else:
        return f(head, acc)

testList = RecList(1, RecList(2, RecList(3, None)))
test = foldr(lambda x, a: RecList(x, a), RecList(None, None), testList)

print test.head
print test.tail.head
```